# How to get the highest value key

Tags: lua

```
function high(scorel)
    local highest = 0
    for name, score in pairs(scorel) do
        if score > highest then 
           highest = score 
        end
    end
    print(name)
end
```

**Print the Key of highest scorer key consist the name of him or her.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to remember the name as well:

```lua
function high(scorel)
    local leader, highest = nil, 0
    for name, score in pairs(scorel) do
        if score > highest then 
           leader, highest = name, score
        end
    end
    return leader, highest
end
print (high(scores)) -- will print leader's name and score.
local leader, record = high(scores)
print (leader) -- abd this will print only the champion's name.
```

Your algorithm will not choose the leader, if everybody's score is the same, but, perhaps, it's what you want.

**UPD**: split leadership:

```lua
function high(scorel)
    local record, leaders = 0, {}
    for name, score in pairs(scorel) do
        if score > record then 
           record = score
           leaders = {name}
        elseif score == record then
           table.insert (leaders, name)
        end
    end
    return leaders, record
end
local leaders, record = high(score)
if #leaders > 0 then
    print ('Highest score (' .. tostring(record) .. ') belongs to ' .. concat (leaders, ', '))
end
```

Comment: That's fine but if I have same score than how can I print both names...?

Comment: @D_S what would you do in real life? you would have alist of leader names. so what do you do if you need a list in Lua? you  use a table or if it is strings you can also append another name to the string...  please try to think of a solution yourself. don't ask everything. this is not how you learn.

Comment: @Piglet   I'm apologize for it, I am an undergrad student I'm new to this Lua it's my 7th day to learning this language I have time constraint to solve progs. I have just this platform to ask any que.  I'll take care about this next time..Sorry...

Comment: no reason to applogize. just keep in mind that you should always formulate solutions in your first language. Take pend and paper and write down all the necessary steps to solve your problem. Then translate it into the programming language of your choice.  asking is good but you should always invest a reasonable amount of time on making your own thoughts and research.

Comment: Thank You for your Guidance sir It will really helps me throughout my learning life.